# How to solution in this warning?

Tags: ios, swift

### Instance method 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' took 225ms to type-check (limit: 50ms)

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        keybordsetting()
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        FIRApp.configure()
        firebase_url = DEV_FIRBASE
         print("screenWidth app : \(width)")

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Post code not screenshots, thanks.

Comment: Please post the whole method, not just the error. (No image)

Comment: That's not an error just warning only

Comment: try to no put anything into that method's body at all – as far as I'm seeing, most of the tasks belong to your root-view-controller `-init` or `-viewDidLoad` not to the `... didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:...`, so you just need to restructure the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To add the flag:**

1. Navigate to your target in Xcode (not the project)
2. Click the “Build Settings” tab
3. Make sure that “All” settings are being shown, not “Basic”
4. Scroll to (or search for) “Other Swift Flags”
5. Add two flags: `-Xfrontend and -warn-long-function-bodies=100`, where 100 is the number of milliseconds you’d like the warning threshold to be
6. Compile your project

Comment: That doesn't fix the warning. It just hides it because you are setting the threshold bigger. It's like you are fixing an inefficiency by changing the rules that determine what is considered inefficient and what is not.